# Linux version of XCOM won't work on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, steam

Every time I try running it, I get

```
Missing executable
```

I tried deleting the app cache folder, re-installing both Steam and XCOM, and verifying the installation files. Nothing worked.

How do I make XCOM work?

Comment: what is the output of the following command 'uname -a'

Answer (score 2):

You can only start XCOM from a 64 Bit Ubuntu installation.

From the [Steam store page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/200510/):

> ### Linux System Requirements
>
> - OS: Ubuntu 14.04 (**64 bit required**)
> - Processor: 2GHz
> - Memory: 4GB Memory
> - Graphics: 512MB
> - Hard Drive:16GB HD space
> - Other Requirements: Nvidia 600 series+, AMD 6000 series+, Intel Iris Pro.
> - IMPORTANT: **Requires 64bit OS to play.**

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while troubleshooting the same issue today and found out that in my case the scripts and binaries were missing the execute permission. Check properties for these files and make sure they can be executed:

- XCom-Enemy-Unknown/xcom.sh
- XCom-Enemy-Unknown/XCOMLauncher
- XCom-Enemy-Unknown/binaries/linux/game.x86_64
- XCom-Enemy-Unknown/binaries/linux/xcom.sh

And if you have Enemy Within:

- XCom-Enemy-Unknown/xew/binaries/linux/game.x86_64
- XCom-Enemy-Unknown/xew/binaries/linux/xcom_ew.sh

The permissions had to be lost as I restored the game from a backup taken from my laptop and the Steam's option to verify game data doesn't check whether permissions have been set up correctly I guess.

Answer (score -1):

Funnily enough, I was just playing XCOM on Ubuntu 14.04 earlier today. Excellent game.

That being said, try looking in your .steam/steam/SteamApps/common/XCom-Enemy-Unknown folder for "XCOMLauncher". Also, make sure "game.x86_64" and "xcom.sh" exist at .steam/steam/SteamApps/common/XCom-Enemy-Unknown/binaries/linux.

Comment: Both of these things are intact and there. So the problem isn't coming from there. Bummer heh.